# Assign a random rgb background color to HTML body via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Title says most of it. I want to add an event to a button that changes the body's background on click. See my code:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var randomColors = [];
    var rgbString = "rgb(";
    for(var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        randomColors[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 + 1));
        if(i < 2){
            rgbString += randomColors[i].toString() + ",";
        }else{
            rgbString += randomColors[i].toString() + ")";
        }
    }
    document.body.style.background = "\"" + rgbString + "\"";
});
```

i've been struggling way too long on this one. Since `console.log("\"" + rgbString + "\"")` returns a proper string, eg. `"rgb(0,55,103)"` i fail to figure out the mistake.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Removing the "\" will work for you but I want to understand why are you using them?

Comment: After all i was just confusing the declaration as quotation marks are required in some cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Roys answer, you need to remove the  `"\"" and "\""` and you could use below logic as well

## ES6

You can create a `function` with random value of rgb color and use [`new Array(3).fill('').map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve result

---

```js
const random=() => Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 + 1));

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
     document.body.style.background = `rgb(${new Array(3).fill('').map(v=>random()).join(',')})`
});
```

```html
<button>Change color</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `"\""` and `"\""` from `document.body.style.background = "\"" + rgbString + "\""`

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var randomColors = [];
    var rgbString = "rgb(";
    for(var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        randomColors[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 + 1));
        if(i < 2){
            rgbString += randomColors[i].toString() + ",";
        }else{
            rgbString += randomColors[i].toString() + ")";
        }
    }
    console.log(rgbString)
    document.body.style.background = rgbString
});
```

```html
<button>
button
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest answer I found

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var randomColors = [];
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    randomColors.push(hue);
    console.log(hue);
    document.body.style.background = hue;
});
```

```html
<button>change color</button>
```